# Magento 2 smtp could not open socket in Aws Setup For M2

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, frontend, backend

My Site is on aws instant and I am used gmail smtp for sending mail from that but I have one sending mail error and try to solve it but not get any solution

[image]

This kind of error I find when I send mail throw gmail smtp in my aws setup magento2.

> Could not open socket: stream_socket_client():
> php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in
> name resolution

I check my php info file in that open ssl was all ready enable

[image]

And I also try to do some code in abstract.php file

[image]

any one can help me how can i solve this thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create The New Smpt Detail in Aws Instance and used it
the aws provide you that service in just 2$ .